# Insert image inside an a link tag

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.4

The code below in not working

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('ilmelogo.png'),array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'feedback')); ?>
```

But this code is working. Help me out

```
<?php   echo $this->Html->image('ilmelogo.png'); ?>
```

Comment: <?php $link = $this->Html->image('ilmelogo.png');                 echo $this->Html->link($link,array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'feedback')); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image('ilmelogo.png'),
    '/pages/feedback',
    array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank')
);
```

OR

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image("ilmelogo.png", array("alt" => "ilme Logo")),
    array(
    'controller' => 'pages',
    'action' => 'feedback'
    )
);
```

Comment: Got the solution thanx `code` echo $this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", array(
    "alt" => "Brownies",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'recipes', 'action' => 'view', 6)
));